# Finding accountshares of a user thats in groups with accountshares

Tags: soql, public-group

My objective is to get a list of `AccountShare` records related to groups where a specific user is in.

How would I write this query?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

`SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId FROM AccountShare WHERE UserOrGroupId IN: 'hereYourUserOrGroup'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `Apex`, you can do it with two queries. I don't believe it can be reduced to one:

```
List<Group> relatedGroups = [
    SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT GroupId FROM GroupMembmer WHERE UserOrGroupId = :userId
    )
];
List<AccountShare> shares = [
    SELECT AccountId FROM AccountShare
    WHERE UserOrGroupId IN :relatedGroups
]
```